# Parallel STXXL Vector Initialization

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, stxxl

The following minimal example illustrates the behaviour of stxxl when initializing containers in parallel (using openMP):

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stxxl.h>

typedef stxxl::VECTOR_GENERATOR<float>::result VEC_T;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const unsigned long NUM = 8;
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(NUM) 
    {       
            VEC_T v;
            printf("%d\t%p\n", omp_get_thread_num(), &v);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

running into either

```
[STXXL-ERROR] File too large
```

or

```
[SYSTEM-ERROR]Segmentation fault
```

How can I allocate  stxxl containers in multiple threads ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initialization of stxxl containers isn't thread-safe, therefore a mutual exclusion for a thread initializing a container is needed. Using openMP, this will read as follows:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stxxl.h>

typedef stxxl::VECTOR_GENERATOR<float>::result VEC_T;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const unsigned long NUM = 8;
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(NUM) 
    {
            VEC_T* v;
            #pragma omp critical
            {
                    v = new VEC_T();
            }
            printf("%d\t%p\n", omp_get_thread_num(), &v);
            delete v;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: And, of course, if the entire purpose of your loop is to construct these container, you will see basically no benefit to running this in OpenMP vs serially because of the ratio of serial to parallel work here.

Comment: Just a minimal example on the concept of parallel initialization

Comment: Are you sure that the initialization of vectors is really not thread-safe? http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/tags/master/faq.html#faq_threadsafe claims that accesses to different data structures from concurrent threads are okay. My guess is that just the first initialization of the STXXL is not thread-safe. When I add a `VEC_T u;` before the parallel section, I do not get any errors anymore.